# Merge two text files into a dictionary on python

Tags: python, dictionary, text, merge

I have two text files that i want to merge ito a dictionary such thatit has all the rows of the first text file, with values from both the first text file, and also the second text file if available. Could someone please help?

For example,

a.txt looks like this :

```
apple 5 7e-6 na 2.2
banana 9 3e-2 2 2.1
orange na 9.2 2.1 na
```

b.txt looks like this :

```
orange 5 6.2 na 6e-3 nd
mango 4 7.3 na 7 3
apple 4 4.4 4.3 na 2
```

I want to merge these two text files on python so that i get an output as followed :

```
apple 5 7e-6 na 2.2 4 4.4 4.3 na 2
banana 9 3e-2 2 2.1 na na na na na
orange na 9.2 2.1 na 5 6.2 na 6e-3 nd
```

I tried making two dictionaries for the two text files and adding them together, using teh following code :

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as document:
    a = {}
    for line in document:
        if line.strip():  # non-empty line?
            key, value = line.split(None, 1) 
            a[key] = value.split()

with open('b.txt', 'r') as document:
    b = {}
    for line in document:
        if line.strip():  # non-empty line?
            key, value = line.split(None, 1) 
            b[key] = value.split()

def combineDict(*args):
    result = {}
    for dic in args:
        for key in (result.viewkeys() | dic.keys()):
            if key in dic:
                if type(dic[key]) is list:
                    result.setdefault(key, []).extend(dic[key])
return result

final = combineDict(a,b)
```

But this keeps all the values in the second text file too (like 'mango')

Comment: Keys are the first value of the split, list append the rest.  That's the hint, otherwise, what have you done? Have you looked up how to process text files, list and string operations, do you have any code?

Comment: please show us your attempt

Comment: did you try anything at all or are you just asking us to do this for you?

Comment: Where did all of the "na na na na ne" values for banana come from? Why isn't mango in the output?

Comment: Sorry for not sharing the code before. You can find it now in the edited output. Also, i do not want mango in the final list as that is not a key in the first text file.

Comment: For banana, there are no values in the second text file, hence i have added 'na' i.e. not available in that key. I hope my question and conditions are making sense.

Comment: Fixed my answer to meet those conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in one file at a time and for each line split into key and values and then add it's values to that key in a database.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import io

file_a = io.StringIO("""apple 5 7e-6 na 2.2
banana 9 3e-2 2 2.1
orange na 9.2 2.1 na""")

file_b = io.StringIO("""orange 5 6.2 na 6e-3 nd
mango 4 7.3 na 7 3
apple 4 4.4 4.3 na 2""")

def dict_from_file(f):
    def line_splitter(line):
        items = line.strip().split()
        return items[0], items[1:]
    # To use filenames, change 'f' above to filename and
    # use this line:
    # with open(filename) as f:
    return {k:v
            for line in f
            for k, v in (line_splitter(line),)}

# Read in initial file
d = dict_from_file(file_a)
# For each additional file append values for already
# existing keys. Extend all values to be the same
# length, filling with 'na'.
files = file_b,
for f in files:
    max_length = 0
    for k, v in dict_from_file(f).items():
        if k in d:
            d[k].extend(v)
            max_length = len(d[k])
    for v in d.values():
        v += ['na'] * (max_length - len(v))

for k, v in d.items():
    print(('{:12} ' + '{:6}' * len(v)).format(k, *v))
```

Output:

```
apple        5     7e-6  na    2.2   4     4.4   4.3   na    2     
banana       9     3e-2  2     2.1   na    na    na    na    na    
orange       na    9.2   2.1   na    5     6.2   na    6e-3  nd
```

Comment: Hi Harvey.. thanks a lot.. i tried this, but it says.. 

`for k, *v in (line.strip().split(),)`
           ^
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

and if i rmove the * in front of v then it syas

`ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: Are you using Python 2? I changed it to work with Python 2. You should be using Python 3. It's so much better than 2, and 2 is either no longer supported or it will be soon.